# Xcode storyboard for different size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I am new in development for iOS/OSX in xcode. I am doing app for iOS in xcode 6 GM. And how can I add new elements like(UIButton,UITextField) but I wanna that these elements are in same position for every resultion (iphone 4 to iphone 6 plus). How can I do it? It is possible or I must code for every resulution different possition?

Thank you for replies.

Comment: Use AutoLayout and create an Adaptable UI in a single Storyboard. There are various tutorials (but only for iOS 7 with multiple storyboards) around; also look at the `WWDC 2014 #216 - Building Adaptive Apps With UIIKit` video (there are also others - just look at the list of WWDC 2014 videos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html). That will solve a lot of your issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me, and don't like using auto layout, you can download my file in the link, and create multiple storyboards and with the names of Main, iPhone5, iPhone6, iPhone6Plus, and in the AppDelegate.swift you would put the code in to call for those story boards for the respectful device.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3o0qhxcqx0yekax/ScreenSizes.zip?dl=0